# Why python os module not giving me the correct file location of the file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, kivy, kivymd

> I want to find get the location of files by just typing the file name and the correct extension
> So in python we normally do this by importing the os module and then typing -: 
> os.path.abspath("file name.extension")
> But my program is not giving me the correct file location I have written this code-:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
import os

helper_string = """
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: scroll

"""


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(helper_string)
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:/'):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith('.mp3'):
                    required_file = file
                    the_location = os.path.abspath(required_file)
                    self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(OneLineListItem(text=required_file, on_release=self.play_song))
                    # print(required_file)

    def play_song(self, onelinelistitem):
        # print('play:', onelinelistitem.text)
        the_song_path = os.path.abspath(onelinelistitem.text)
        sound = SoundLoader.load(the_song_path)
        if sound:
            sound.play()
        print(the_song_path)


MainApp().run()
```

> **You can just ignore the SoundLoader.load code and all the other kivy code**
> Now when the code runs we have to select a file and it will print the file location on the console
> But it is printing the wrong location and hence, the SoundLoader is not able to load the files...
> ***For example a song in my computer is on this location -:
>
> C:\Users\SAMARTH KUMAR PANDEY\Downloads\SHAREit\V1.12\music\Godzilla (feat. Juice WRLD) [Official Audio].mp3
>
> But on the console it is printing this path -: 
>
> C:\Users\SAMARTH KUMAR PANDEY\PycharmProjects\Kivy\venv\Godzilla (feat. Juice WRLD) [Official Audio].mp3***
> But the fact is that I do not have any songs in my *C:\Users\SAMARTH KUMAR PANDEY\PycharmProjects\Kivy\venv* folder
> Can anyone help me out please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[os.path.abspath](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html) will return the absolute path from the current directory which in your case is "C:\Users\SAMARTH KUMAR PANDEY\PycharmProjects\Kivy\venv"

What you might want to do is to join the path to your traversal like

```
the_location = os.path.join(root, required_file)
```

PS: You don't need to create the reference to required_file. You can use file.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked...by the way why that didn't worked?

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your question. If you mean the current directory settings, it comes from where you run python (in this case the PyCharm settings).

Comment: @nitishr I got it, so it showed my current pycharm directory